# Load data from one page Textbox to another page textbox?

Tags: asp.net, html

I Have a ASP.Net login page in which I enter my login credentials. when I click submit I want this data to be entered in gmail.com username and password textboxes respectively but it should not login in gmail itshould just enter the details. How to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to navigate to www.gmail.com with your own data filled in the username and password textbox?

Comment: If so, I think you can open www.gmail.com as your child window, then you can pass your data to the username element in this child window using javascript. (of course, your should have stored your data in the parent page), I can provide some sample code if you need.

Comment: yes. I want to do that exactly

Comment: can it be done with out creating a child window.

Comment: @AbhayKumar: You cannot just post data or values from one web-application to another (both being on a different domain). Only way to do this is by making a Win-Form application and using the Web-Browser control.

Comment: I will try searching on this thx @Tathagat Verma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use session to store your login credentials and use it where you wish.

Comment: how do i do with session. I want to do this exactly with gmail.com

Comment: whenever you click on submit put your login name and password in session and on the page where you want to retrive fill the textboxes with their session values

Comment: How do i load the data in www.gmail.com using session. can you give some reference

Comment: @Abhay http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent78.aspx this is what you have to do.

Comment: Thanks Neha. Not exactly i wanna do that but i got an idea

Comment: @Neha: This link doesn't have reference to the required question and/or solution. The requirement specifies posting data to an external-site (gmail.com in this case). You'll have no control over the code of the destination-site.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to google cookies , and adjust it,